# How to "Alt+Left Arrow" puppeteer page.keyboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, keyboard-events

i new with puppeteer js, i currently making automation for page and there are the task that the programs need going back to the previous page
i want to make my page back to history without using
`page.goBack();` function, so i think i will do this command "Alt+left arrow"

i have my script like this:

```
await page.keyboard.down('Alt');
await page.keyboard.press('ArrowLeft');
await page.keyboard.up('Alt');
```

but nothing happened, there was no error too.

when i run this `await page.keyboard.down('Alt');` it looks like nothing happened,

when i run this `await page.keyboard.down('ArrowLeft');` its apparently works fine,
please kindly help me

fyi, i'm using Windows OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the keycode of ALT, like this:

```js
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(18))
```

18 is the character code of the ALT key.

Comment: thanks for answerin, BUT i aready use this code too but nothing happened too, because the thing is i want to do "ALT+ Left arrow" in page, i think it cuase by type method so alt pressed and then not waiting for the left arrow?

Comment: Yes, It wasn't clear that you were trying to emulate a keystroke combination.